# How to synchronize the actions of a subscribed function

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I'm developing an angular 7 application. I have an http post request with an error handler called in the catchError function.
In the error handler I need to translate the http status code in a user friendly message, I use ngx-translate for this purpose. I want the error handler to return an Observable with the translated error message via the throwError function. To do that, in the error handler, I assign a variable in the subscribe function of the TranslateService, since the operation is asynchronous what is the best and cleaner way to be sure that the variable with the translation is ready before the error handler returns the observable?

```
postRequest(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(reqUrl, body)
    .pipe(...some transformations on data)
    .catchError(this.handlerError.bind(this)) 
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse | any): Observable<any> {
  let error_message = 'Generic error occurred';
  let error_message_key = '';

  switch (error.status) {
    case 400:
      error_message_key = 't.validation.bad_request';
      break;
    case 401:
      error_message_key = 't.validation.login_credentials_invalid';
      break;
    case 403:
      error_message_key = 't.validation.unauthorized';
      break;

    .....other cases
  }

  if (error_message_key !== '') {
    this.translate.get(error_message_key).subscribe( t => {
       error_message = t;
    });
  }

  return throwError(error_message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `catchError` callback should return a stream -- you can just switch to translation service stream.

Substituting this part

```
if (error_message_key !== '') {
  this.translate.get(error_message_key).subscribe( t => {
     error_message = t;
  });
}
```

with

```
if (error_message_key !== '') {
  return this.translate.get(error_message_key)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(throwError)
    )
}
```

Should work.

*Please, note that depending on the actual use case, [switchMap](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/switchMap) might not be ideal for you. So check [concatMap](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/concatMap) and [mergeMap](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/mergeMap) as well*

Hope this helps